# tableView delegate and datasource

Tags: ios, swift

I'm learning Swift. Sometimes I see that Main.Storyboard is used to set up the `tableView` `delegate` and `dataSource` (ctrl+click and so on). Sometimes I see that it's done through coding instead like so:

```
// create the variable for the tableview
IBOutlet weak var someTableView : UITableView!
// setup delegate and datasource
sefl.someTableView.delegate = self
self.someTableView.datasource = self
```

I do understand how it works with second way. But it's difficult to realize how it works through Main.Storyboard with no IBOutlet setup.

Thank you for your responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works exactly the same way :)

Let me refresh the principle:

You have a class, provided by Apple in this case, that has to work for a lot of scenario. Apple decided to use a kind of inversion of control, called delegation, where the workflow is inverted (hence the name) : instead of the view controller giving order to the tableView by calling methods on it, it is the tableView that goes and fetch its orders from the controller by calling methods on it.
In order to achieve this kind of IoC (inversion of control), the TableView MUST know the "address" of the object it has to ask for its order. Like you have to know your boss' email address to ask him stuff. So, the UITableView class as a property called dataSource that means to store that address. 
Now as a ViewController programmer, you have to set this property to be the address of the view controller that will give the order to that tableview.
2 ways of doing it :

in code : in the view controller, you have a property pointing to the tableview (if linked from the storyboard, it is called indeed an IBOutlet, but doesn't have to be) and you set it's delegate property to self. (meaning 'hey tableView, your boss is myself)

Or you do it in the storyboard, because the graphic template for the tableView let you ctrl+drag from the tableView to the ViewController and set the datasource connection. In this case it will be the storyboard who will have to find the address of the tableView (since it is the one creating it, it's kinda easy) and setting it's delegate property to be the address of the view controller (meaning hey tableView, your boss will be this guy)

Either way, the viewController has to be ready to answer all the question from the TableView, so conforming to the UITableViewDataSource protocol.
the delegate scenario is the same.

Comment: Please, introduce formatting here. And avoid common speech like "meaning hey tableView, your boss will be this guy".

Comment: edit: format introduced, as for the common speech, I though it will be more clear in a teaching purpose. Feel free to edit if you wish

Comment: Nothing against it. I'd just prefer a more neutral speech.

Comment: Yeah but I'm french :p Showing code is easy, but explain a pattern or a way of thinking tends to be more difficult in a foreign langage. I'm doing what I can to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand how the loading of views works in iOS. Your xib will be translated into the hierarchy of views and they are loaded onto the memory. When you make an IBOutlet of those views, you'll have a *reference* of that loaded view in your code. If you do not create an IBOutlet, it doesn't mean that the view isn't there. It is there and it is in the memory.

When you set the `delegate` and the `dataSource` of a `tableView` and when the tableView is loaded onto the memory, it sets the delegate and the dataSource of the loaded `tableView` to the class as specified by you. It doesn't matter if you do not have a *reference* to it.